# ASP.NET: Is there a way to get the URL of HttpGet?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have something like this:

```
public class BackendLoginModule : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("/backend/login")]  // <- URL is "/backend/login"
    public IActionResult login()
    {
        //prepare login page
    }

    [HttpGet("/backend/logout")]
    public IActionResult logout()
    {
        //clear session and
        string url = "/backend/login"; // <- reference to login without writing it hardcoded?
        return Redirect(url);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to replace the hardcoded "/backend/login" string with a reference to the logout() function?

Simliar to Java/SpringBoot, there is a possibility to get the URL this way:

```
String url = linkTo(methodOn(BackendLoginModule.class).login()).withRel("Create").getHref();
//value of url is now pointing to "/backend/login"
```

Comment: One of the base functionality implemented in the **MVC** is converting _incoming URL_ (routes) to _outgoing URL_. Therefore the URL you wrote (`/backend/login`) compound of two segments (`/controller/action`) is an _incoming URL_. Are you looking to some method that will convert your specific route to the _outgoing URL_ in your code?

Comment: Looked for a way to get the URL without writing it hardcoded. For example if (for whatever reason) a link changes ("/backend/login" => "/backendlogin"). In that case I need to search all ocurrences of "/backend/login" and replace it with "/backendlogin". With the "naming solution" (accepted answer) I just have to change the URL once in the whole code and there will be no invalid URLs (because the internal used name stays always the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a route name to Login action like below:

```
[HttpGet("/backend/login",Name ="Login")]
public IActionResult login()
{
    return View();
}
```

Then you can use `Url.RouteUrl(RouteName)` to get the url:

```
public IActionResult logout()
{
    var url = Url.RouteUrl("Login");

    return View();
}
```